# How to reference a counter outside of a for loop?

Tags: python

I came across a question in Hackerank. An e-commerce website contains one to many items in each page. To mimic the logic of the website, a programmer has a list of items and each item is in the form of a string array: [name, relevance, price] where each value of relevance and price are integers as strings. After sorting the items by (name:0, relevance :1, price:2), the programmer is trying to find out a list of items displayed in a chosen page. Given a list of items, the sort column, the sort order (0 : ascending, 1: descending), the number of items to be displayed in each page and a page number. Determine the list of item names in the specified page while respecting the item's order (Page number starts at 0). Example items = [[item1, 10, 15), [item2, 3, 4), (item3, 17, 8]] sortParameter = 1 sortOrder = 0 itemsPerPage = 2 pageNumber = 1 there are n = 3 items. • Sort them by (relevance : 1) in ascending order (items = [[item2, 3, 4], [item1, 10, 15). [item3, 17, 8]]). Display up to 2 items in each page. • The page O contains 2 item names [item2, item1] and page 1 contains only 1 item name, result = item3. Function Description Complete the function fetchitemsToDisplay in the editor below. fetchltemsToDisplay has the following parameter(s): string items[n][3]: a 2D array of arrays of strings in the form (name, relevance, price] int sortParameter: the column of the items to sort on int sortOrder:0 = ascending and 1 = descending int itemsPerPage: the number of items per page int pageNumber: the page number to display item names Returns: string pageltems[m]: array of item names on the requested page in the order they are displayed
Returns: string pageltems[m]: array of item names on the requested page in the order they are displayed

Now, I am done with the sorting part and also most of the test cases pass but as you can see in the output I get, the pagenumbers seem to repeat. I have tried many approaches but I can't seem to figure out how to manage the count? I think I need a fresh perspective on this one.

```
def fetchitemstoDisplay(stringitems,sortparameter,sortorder,itemsperpage,pagenumber):
  p=sortparameter
  if sortorder==0:
    so=False
  else:
    so=True
  try:
    a=(sorted(stringitems, key = lambda x: int(x[p]),reverse=so))
  except ValueError:
    a=(sorted(stringitems, key = lambda x: x[0],reverse=False))
  tn=[]
  pn=0
  m=0
  for i in range(len(a)):
    if m<=itemsperpage-1:
      tn.append([pn,a[i][0]])
      m+=1
    elif m>itemsperpage-1 and itemsperpage==1:
      m=0
      pn+=1
      tn.append([pn,a[i][0]])
      pn+=1
    elif m>itemsperpage-1:
      m=0
      pn+=1
      tn.append([pn,a[i][0]])
  print(tn )
  for i in tn:
    if(i[0])==pagenumber:
      print(i[1])
    else:
      pass
```

```
fetchitemstoDisplay([['p1','1','2'],['p2','2','1'],['p3','2','1'],['p5','2','1'],['p6','2','1'],['p6','2','1']],0,1,2,0)
```

```
[[0, 'p1'], [0, 'p2'], [1, 'p3'], [1, 'p5'], [1, 'p6'], [2, 'p6']]
```

Comment: You may have the most luck if you narrow the description and code to just  the problem you want to address. If this is about a counter in a loop a half-dozen lines is likely all you need. We want to know what "outside of the loop" means - is is after the loop? In a different function you call? A different thread? So far we have what seems to be the first chapter of War And Peace to work with.

Comment: Sorry, about that. I am new over here. I just provided the entire thing to have a better context. Let me try to simplify it. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Sounds good. Its a good practice for debugging in general, especially with python where experimenting is very easy.

Comment: Does this make sense? Say you have an list, `a=[['p1', '1', '2'], ['p2', '2', '1'], ['p3', '2', '1'], ['p5', '2', '1'], ['p6', '2', '1'], ['p6', '2', '1']]`. Now you have parameter called itemsperpage, let's say it is equal to 2. So, now the task is to create a new list as follows. `n=[[0,'p1'],[0,'p2],[1,'p3'],[1,'p5'],[2,'p6],[2,'p6]]`. The first element of this new list would depend on the parameter itemsperpage.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I can propose an answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pages by enumerating the list and doing floor division on the index. If you want 2 items per page, index `(0//2, 1//2, 2//2, 3//2, ...)` become `(0, 0, 1, 1, etc...)` and you can build your return list from there.

```
>>> def get_pages(data_list, items_per_page):
...     return [[i//items_per_page, data[0]] for i, data in enumerate(data_list)]
... 
>>> 
>>> a=[['p1', '1', '2'], ['p2', '2', '1'], ['p3', '2', '1'], ['p5', '2', '1'], ['p6', '2', '1'], ['p6', '2', '1']]
>>> 
>>> print(get_pages(a,2))
[[0, 'p1'], [0, 'p2'], [1, 'p3'], [1, 'p5'], [2, 'p6'], [2, 'p6']]
```

Comment: Ok. This seems to be working when items_per_page is 2. This is what I get when I pass items_per_page is 3 `` [[0, 'p1'], [0, 'p2'], [1, 'p3'], [1, 'p5'], [2, 'p6'], [2, 'p6']]``. The expected o/p should be ``[[0, 'p1'], [0, 'p2'], [0, 'p3'], [1, 'p5'], [1, 'p6'], [1, 'p6']]``

Comment: Looks like I wasn't using the passed parameter. Fixed.